# How to plot N-species Lotka-Volterra equation in Mathematica

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, chaos-theory

Sorry. I wasn't aware that the article was no longer free elsewhere from an educational address. [Here is another link to this article](https://mega.nz/#!gNQGDbiZ!bqPwJE17LDbF97JGAEDUT-x8IfQO7twzvCQeKsioytA). Please view only and ignore the highlight I wrote. I will delete the link as soon as possible.

I am reading through [Coexistence and chaos in complex ecologies](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0375960104017955), but I am unsure how they were able to come up with the graph derived from $$\frac{dx_i}{dt}=r_ix_i\left(1-\sum_{j=1}^{N}a_{ij}x_j\right)$$ $$M = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i$$ $$D = 1 - \frac{1}{2(N-1)}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left | \frac{x_i}{m}-1 \right |$$
**My questions are: Are there ways in Mathematica that I can replicate their results? Also, how can I calculate Lyapunov exponent as they did in the paper? Thanks!**

Thanks!

Below are the graphs I was referring to. 
[image: Here]
[image]
[image]